# Writing non-string value into io.Writer Write method

Tags: go, byte

I'm trying to write non-string value into `io.Writer` like integer, float, slices, or even map[string]interface{}. I'm expecting the result written returned as expected type written. If I wrote int into the Write, then I will get integer type value after decoding the []byte returned. How to do it in Go?

Comment: You have to encode the data in some form, json is one possibility, and decode it when you read it.

Comment: I fail to parse the question but it _looks_ like you're asking for what is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)? If yes, the possibilities are many, starting from `encoding/binary` and proceeding into `encoding/gob`, `encoding/json`, protocol buffers and gazillions of others.

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably looking for is [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) since that encoding retains the Go type information. Out of the box it supports some of the builtin Go types and some of the basic `gob` types. If you want to encode/decode types not supported out of the box by `gob` you can use the `gob.Register` function to register those types.

To encode:

```golang
var v interface{} = uint8(123)
if err := gob.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&v); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Note that the above passes a value of type `*interface{}` to `Encode`, this is necessary if, at the other end, the decoder doesn't know the type beforehand and has to also use type `*interface{}` as the argument to `Decode`. If you have a scenario where the decoder knows the concrete type the of the incoming data then you can also pass a value of that concrete type to `Encode`.

---

To decode:

```golang
var v interface{}
if err := gob.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&v); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(v)      // output: 123
fmt.Printf("%T", v) // output: uint8
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cCtQse8BoqZ

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
   a := []interface{}{
      31, 3.1, []int{12,31}, map[string]interface{}{"month": 12, "day": 31},
   }
   b, err := json.Marshal(a)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   println(string(b)) // [31,3.1,[12,31],{"day":31,"month":12}]
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal